# Use of Lim Sup in proof, rather than Lim

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf, probability-limit-theorems

In my textbook on Advanced Probability it reads

"Definition: $X_n$ converges in probability to X if for all $\epsilon >0$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n-X| \geq \epsilon) = 0$"

Now in a lemma, we set out to prove that $X_n$ also converges in probability to $X$ if and only if for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n-X| > \epsilon) = 0$.

Now in the proof, proving the "if" direction, they fix $\epsilon > 0$ and reason (without further argument)

$${\lim \sup}_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n -X| \geq \epsilon) \leq {\lim \sup}_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon/2) $$

and from here conclude that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n-X| \geq \epsilon) = 0$.

I have two questions:

- Why use Lim Sup, rather than ordinary Lim, when the definition only concerns the limit?
- Why is this inequality "obviously" true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality follows from the fact that the event $|X_n-X| \geq \epsilon$ is contained in the event $|X_n-X| >\epsilon/2$. Recall that $A \subseteq B$ implies $P(A) \leq P(B)$.

When you want to prove that $a_n \to 0$ (where $a_n \geq 0$ ) but you don't know that $\lim a_n$ exists you start with $\lim \sup a_n$. But once you show that $\lim \sup a_n=0$  you can conclude that $\lim a_n$ exist and is $0$.

Comment: Why do we not consider Lim Inf then? Is the reason that we are working in probability scope where P > 0 ?

Comment: @Fabric Proving that $\lim \inf a_n=0$ does not guarntee that $\lim a_n=0$. For example take $a_n=0$ for $n$ even and $1$ for $n$ odd.

Comment: But how about a sequence $a_n = 0$ for $n$ even and $a_n = -1$ for $n$ odd. Then $\lim \sup a_n = 0$ but $\lim a_n \neq 0$, right?

Comment: When you prove something you prove it in generality. You cannot prove it for a particular case.   So your example does not say that you can use $\lim \inf$ instead of $\lim \sup$  in the proof. @Fabric

Comment: @Fabric: "Why do we not consider Lim Inf then?" For any sequence $a_n$ we have $\liminf a_n \leq \limsup a_n,$ and if each $a_n$ is non-negative (i.e. each $a_n \geq 0),$ then we also have $\liminf a_n \geq 0.$ So for any sequence $a_n$ of **non-negative** real numbers, we have $0 \leq \liminf a_n \leq \limsup a_n,$ and hence if we prove $\limsup a_n = 0,$ then it follows that $0 \leq \liminf a_n \leq \limsup a_n = 0,$ and thus have equality throughout. Therefore, $\liminf a_n = \limsup a_n$ (i.e. $\lim a_n$ exists) and $\lim a_n = 0$ (because $\limsup a_n = 0$ and $\limsup a_n = \lim a_n).$